# Get return values while extracting the .rpm file

Tags: python, shell, rpm

I am allowing the users to upload a .rpm file from my website.
I am using `sudo rpm -ivh $1 --nodeps` command inside a script file to extract .rpm whose name is being passed as parameter. I want to to check that the file user just uploaded and want to install is already there in the system or not and display proper message to the user before running the above command (or is there a way to check so that my script returns a value on bases of which i can take decision)..

The output of the command is
           `Preparing... ########################################### [100%]`
           `package testing_rpm is already installed`
It doesn't return some numeric value..

Is there a way(better way) to do that.?

Comment: *It doesn't return some numeric value* how did you checked it?

Comment: I ran the command manually and checked on the terminal.. If we run this command like `rpm -i name_of_file --nodeps` it will output nothing if package installed successfully and will print *package testing is already installed*

Comment: if its bash, last command's exit status can be obtained with **$?**

Comment: @tuxuday Exactly. Unfortunately, `rpm`'s exit code is, apparently, quite useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you want to see the files associated with an RPM, run an `rpm -qpl` against it.  This will give you a list of the files that the rpm has in it without trying to install it.

Here's the command run against the tomcat rpm where you can see all the files that this package will install:

[image: example of rpm -qpl]

You could also just do an `rpm -q` and look for "not installed":

[image: example of -q]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. To do the same I wrote a script    
     `pckgName=rpm -qp test-1.10.1-1.noarch.rpm`,    
     `pckgExist=rpm -qa | grep $pckgName`,    
     `if [ "$pckgExist" ]`, 
`then`, 
`echo "Package already installed"`,
`exit 1`,
`else`, 
`echo "do something else"`....

Answer (score 2):

See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/178271/167825).

`rpm` returns a non-zero exit status when one or more of the specified actions fail and thus apparently `1` if the package is already installed on your system which seems indistinguishable from failing to install one package, you have to parse the output of the `rpm` command. If the installation of the package(s) succeed it should return with a zero exit code `0`.